# robot NAO object detection from scratsh

Tags: python, neural-network, yolo, nao-robot, naos-project

is it possible to create my own object detection script with YOLO or create a Neuron Network  to implement it in the NAO robot( iknow that there is a box of detection in choregraph but isn't very useful that's why i want to build an other one from scratch )  .. if there are any resources or something else that help me not hesitate to put them and thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not easy.
You could use TensorFlow or PyTorch and run YOLO on a PC connected to NAO using PyNAOqi, to get images from the camera.

These Python packages are not available on NAO, because it is lacking `pip` and compilers.
Most advanced developers should be able to compile neural networks into binaries that can run on the robot using the NAOqi C++ SDK, but honestly they must be rare.